# How to use a Ternary Operator with multiple condition in flutter dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, ternary-operator

how to use ternary if else with two or more condition using "OR" and "AND" like

```
    if(foo == 1 || foo == 2)
     {
      do something
      }
     {
      else do something
      }
```

i want to use it like

```
  foo == 1 || foo == 2 ? doSomething : doSomething
```

Comment: Use parentheses to group expressions.

Comment: You can use parantheses to use logical "OR" and "AND".

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing? The code `foo == 1 || foo == 2 ? doSomething : doSomething` is valid, even without extra parentheses.

Comment: I would argue a slightly different point - _why_ ternary over if/else? - Don't obfuscate the readability of your code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 86):

If you're referring to else if statements in dart, then this ternary operator:

```
(foo==1)? something1():(foo==2)? something2(): something3();
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if(foo == 1){
    something1();
}
elseif(foo == 2){
    something2();
}
else something3();
```

Comment: Nice. so `?` and `:` just alternate always

Comment: The `?` marks the end of the condition and the `:` simply means else

Answer (score 15):

For three conditions use:

`value: (i == 1) ? 1 : (i == 2) ? 2 : 0`

Comment: You dont have to be rude and give negative vote to him. He has given the idea to use multiple ternary operator. I dont see anything wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> Try below

```
(2 > 3)?print("It is more than 3"):print("It is less than 3");
////Prints It is less than 3 to the console
```

Answer (score 3):

For AND try this,
// here both or multiple conditions needs to satisfy

```
if (primaryImageUploaded == true && signatureImageUploaded == true) {
    // status bool condition in true 
    } else {
     // if false 
    }
```

For OR try this,
// here need ONLY any one condition to satisfy

```
if (primaryImageUploaded == true || signatureImageUploaded == true) {
    // status bool condition in true 
    } else {
     // if false 
    }
```

Another Dart Syntax

```
if (100 > 50) {
  print("100 is greater than 50");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`foo == 1 ? doSomething1 : (foo == 2 ? doSomething1 : doSomething2)`

If you have to include multiple conditions then you should use parantheses

Answer (score 2):

it is easy,

```
if(foo == 1 || foo == 2)
 {
  do something
  }
 {
  else do something
  }
```

it can be written thus for `OR` statement

`foo==1 || foo==2 ? do something : else do something`

it can be written thus for `AND` statement

`foo==1 && foo==2 ? do something : else do something`

both will work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED**

The original answer has run a little bit of from the question asked. Below is my edited answer.

To use ternary operator

```
(foo == 1 || foo == 2) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

For my cleaner approach

```
{1, 2}.contains(foo) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

**ORIGINAL**

The cleaner way for me is

```
if ({1, 2}.contains(foo)) {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the cleanest form for my case and reduced around 80 lines of code :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the same

```
Text((managerStatus == "pending")
    ? "Requested"
        : (adminStatus == "confirm")
    ? "Amount credited"
        : "Admin Pending")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Multiple check in one condition

```
if(in_array($foo, [1,2,'other'])) {
    //do something
}
else {
    //else do something
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
void main(){
  var a,b,c,d;  
  a = 7;  
  b = 9;  
  c = 11;  
  d = 15;  
  print((a>b)?((a>c)?((a>d)?a:d):c):(b>c)?((b>d)?b:d):(c>d)?c:d);
}
```