# Flutter Login/Logout button Visibility based on user logged In/logged Out

Tags: flutter

I have implemented Login and Logout button but not knowing how to show/hide button (List in Listview). Buttons are in Listview (inside drawer) and want to show button at top login and if user is logged in want to show Logout at end of Listview

userid to verify if logged in is stored in shared preference

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dynamic userid = prefs.getInt('userId');
```

```
Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> LoginandSignupScreen()));
              },
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();

              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomeScreen()));},
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Text(
                      'Logout',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You must maintain the bool to know whether user is logged in or not. in your case you can have a ternary operator to verify this, similar to this you can apply for login

```
userid != null ? Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();

              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomeScreen()));},
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Text(
                      'Logout',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ) : Container();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple way to show you how you can achieve this.

Assuming if the `userid` is not there, then it returns `null` to your `userid` variable.

Now, in `Flutter`, you can do a `check` and based upon that, you can show/hide something.

```
var somthing = data

if(something != null) // show your Widget
else Container() // this is usually done to show the empty widget, which is as good as hiding the data and showing up a non-space taking widget
```

Now in your current situation, you can show/hide your buttons based upon the above methodology. We use a conditional operator called `ternary operator`. You can read [more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584973/5362583).

```
// If user is not logged in, then Login will not show up, that means userid should be null
userid == null ? 
 Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
   child: InkWell(
       onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> LoginandSignupScreen()));
       },
       child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
             Expanded(flex: 2, child: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
             Expanded(
               flex: 10,
               child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)))
          ]
       )
    )
 ) : Container(), // if the userid is not null then Container() will be shown,
// If user is logged in, then Logout will not show up, that means userid should not be null
userid != null ? 
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: (){
       Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();

       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomeScreen()));},
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
               Expanded(flex: 2, child: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
               Expanded(
               flex: 10,
               child: Text('Logout',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)))
             ]
       )
    )
 ) : Container() // if the userid is null then Container() will be shown
```

This is how you deal with it.

Comment: How can i get userId stored in shared Preference and how do i declare var.. apologies, but this is my first attempt to create an app and just learning flutter.

Comment: I am making use of your `userid` only @chetansuri. `dynamic userid = prefs.getInt('userId');` via this code only. Now you utilize your `userid` to show/hide specific buttons as shown in the answer.